# reportviewer.getparameters retrieves SSRS wromg parameter dependencies

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, dependencies, reportviewer

I'm using SSRS 2008R2 in an ASP.NET website and use the ReportViewer control to display it.

We have a report with 4 parametrs with the follwing dependencies betwwn them:
1. P2 + P3 depend on P1
2. P4 depends on P3

We used ReportViewer.Serverreport.getParameters() function to retrieve the ReportParameterInfo Collection and got the correct data:

```
P1 - 0 dependencies + 2 dependents
P2 - 1 dependencies + 1 dependents
P3 - 1 dependencies + 0 dependents
P4 - 1 dependencies + 0 dependents
```

Now we wanted to enable the report to fit to multiple customers so we added ServerName + DBName parameters to the report and used them in the report's Data Source thus making it dynamic but to my surprise the above function does not retrieve the expected results, I would expect it to say that all the above parameters depend on the ServerName + DBName and the rest of the depencies will remain as they were but I'm getting the follwing result:

```
ServerName - 0 dependencies + 4 dependents - as expected 
DBName - 0 dependencies + 4 dependents - as expected
P1 - 2 dependencies + 3 dependents - **why 3 dependents? should remain 2**
P2 - 3 dependencies + 2 dependents - **why 2 dependents? should remain 1**
P3 - 4 dependencies + 1 dependents - **why 1 dependents? should remain 0
                                     why 4 dependencies ? should be 3**
P4 - 5 dependencies + 0 dependents - **why 5 dependencies ? should be 3**
```

Now, this apperently wrong result makes us a lot of trouble since we have great deal of functionality depending on these parameter dependencies.

Did anybody encounter something similar, any ideas? workarounds?